# String and integer confused??? Bash

Tags: string, bash, unix, int

I'm wrinting a script in bash

I have an array and i want to add if i found a Id = to the $i variable otherwise i want to add the text null and increment the until  both variables arethe same value

Example:

$i=10101

$Id can take this values (10101, 10102, 10105, 10107)

This is part of my code

```
txts=()
for line in $(cat file.txt)
do
    Id="$(echo $line | cut -d ' ' -f1)"
    #I want to know how to transform the Id into a int ????
    eId=$(echo $Id + 0) 
    txt="$(echo $line | cut -d ':' -f2)"
    if [[ $i -eq $eId ]]; then
       txts+=("$txt")
       i=$((i+1))
    else
        for (( c=$i; c=$eId; c++))
        do
            txts+=("null")
            i=$((i+1))
        done
        i=$(($eId))
    fi
done
```

## Edited Code using [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/):

```
txts=()
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
Id=$(echo "$line" | cut -d ' ' -f1)
eId=$(echo $Id + 0) 
txt="$(echo line | cut -d ':' -f2)"
if [[ $i -eq $eId ]]; then
   txts+=("$txt")
   i=$((i+1))
else
    for (( c=i; c=eId; c++))
    do
        txts+=("null")
        i=$((i+1))
    done
    i=$((eId))
fi
done < "Vlan_Port.txt"
```

Output:

```
./script.sh: line 27: = + 0: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "= + 0")
```

Is this Possible? Please explain why.

## Edit 1

the starting index is 10101

I have a file with an index and a text and i want to know if they are on order if not put them and if there are missing indexes them put the text null and in the end what i want for the example i gave above is an array containning:

10101
10102
null
null
10105
null
10107

Comment: Bunch of syntax issues, use http://www.shellcheck.net to fix them

Comment: Just state your input with an output required

Comment: thnks for the shellchek will use

Comment: @Inian thanks for the syntax errors though i still remain with the same problem that is i can't compara $i that is int with $Id that is a string can i? So how do i turn it into int?

Comment: Do you have to do this in `bash`? You just want to fill the gaps with the appropriate numbers based on the key right? did you look up `Awk`?

Comment: yes i have to use bash it was asked to me to do it but i'm having some troubles doing ti too. No but i will look into it , in the meantime any examples you coul help with

Comment: Bash doesn't make a distinction between strings and ints.  There is no need to convert them.  If you want to add a something to a string, just do it. `echo $(( $(echo 1) + $(echo 1) ))` prints "2".  I'm confused by the line with the `cut` and the `-d ':'`.  You didn't mention the use of the colon in your description of the syntax.  How does it play a role?  And what is line 27, is it the `eId=$(echo $Id + 0)` line?  Why the `||` clause in the first `while`? It seems to me it would read forever because you're ignoring EOF from read if `line` is non-null.

Comment: Try breaking it down into manageable parts.  You ask whether you can compare $i that is int with $Id that is a string.  Come up with a smaller test case and try it, e.g. `i="3"; echo $(( ${i} + 1 ))`.  Remember you can do all this stuff on the command line as a test to experiment with.  Go through it step by step instead of trying to write the whole script at once. I think you're logic is on the right track, but if and only if the input is already ordered.  If it isn't, and you say it isn't, you'll need to store the whole file in an array before doing anything.

Comment: @eewanco hi so due to what you were saying the `cut  -d ':'` it is because it has lot's of "trash info" in the middle and i separated it using cut that's only why . And to answer about line 27, yes , it was  in order to try to put them and both as integer but as i've seen it doesn't type the variables... Anyway then why use `-eq` or `=` ??? And why the || me myself i can't completely understand the while loop that's why i originally used a `for in` but someone recommended me to use shellcheker and the program itself advised me to change it into an while loop. How can i compare them?

Comment: `-eq` is used for numeric comparison along with `-ne`, `-lt`,`gt`, etc. `=`, `!=`, and so forth are used for string comparison. `[ "01234" -eq 1234 ] && echo yes` echoes `yes` but `[ "01234" = 1234 ] && echo yes` does not.  By the way in some versions of bash you can declare an integer variable in bash using `declare -i` but I'm not sure what practical difference that has. Also you can again in some versions of bash use the `let` command to assign numerical expressions to a variable; `let a=b+c` or `let a++`.